# variables containing Post elements get empty after another post called

Tags: php, html, post

i have a problem keeping a post element in variables before calling one more time post in a second form .

briefly:
variable below contain elements from previous post

```
$img=isset($_POST['image'])?$_POST['image']:false;
$table=isset($_POST['tabl'])?$_POST['tabl']:false;
```

Then i have as next to the lines above the form below :

```
<form method="post" action="" style="padding-top:200px;padding-bottom:200px;padding-left:500px">

<div><span>Email</span></div>  <input type="text" value="" name="user"/><br><br>
<div><span>Password</span></div>  <input type="password" value="" name="pass"/><br><br>
       <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>
 </form>
```

and right after pressing submit `$img` and `$table` are both empty .

how can i keep the values in `$img`and `$table` even after calling post again ?

any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: You'll either have to submit them again with the second form (Maybe as hidden input fields) or store them in a DB / SESSION / Cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't sending the variables you want in the POST data in your second form.

You could use a hidden field to send it,

A bit like this.

```
   <form method="post" action="" style="padding-top:200px;padding-bottom:200px;padding-left:500px">
    <input type="hidden" name="img" value="<?php echo $img;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="table" value="<?php echo $table;?>" />
    <div><span>Email</span></div>  <input type="text" value="" name="user"/><br><br>
    <div><span>Password</span></div>  <input type="password" value="" name="pass"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: yeah i just thought about it thank you very much . i just realized that i needed to post again the value img and table !!